# CMake protobuf_generate Succeeds But Doesn't Generate Code

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-c++

I am attempting to build a C++ (C++11) project using gRPC with CMake (v 3.26.4) as the build system, and after spending the last few days fighting with CMake I think I am finally close. I am successfully building `gRPC` from source and then linking it's output to process later steps in CMake for my `.proto` files. But now I really don't know how to proceed

What's happening is that I finally have my gRPC code building. The `cmake` command exits successfully, and everything looks great... but the C++ header / source files never get generated. I've searched my entire computer (all drives) and the files are nowhere. And there is no error code, so I don't even know how to investigate.

My file structure looks roughly like:

```
root/
├─CMakeList.txt
├─service/
| ├─CMakeLists.txt
| ├─proto
|   ├─CMakeLists.txt
|   ├─service.proto
├─third_party
| ├─CMakeLists.txt
| ├─grpc
| ├─abseil
```

And my `root/service/proto/CMakeLists.txt` file (which is called via recursive `add_subdirectory()` calls) looks like:

```
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
if(MSVC)
  add_definitions(-D_WIN32_WINNT=0x600)
endif()

# Link in third_party libraries needed for code generation
target_link_libraries(my_project
    PRIVATE
        protobuf
        grpc++
        grpc_plugin_support)


# Get the environment variables needed for later.
set(pb_cmake ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/third_party/grpc/third_party/protobuf/cmake/protobuf/protobuf-generate.cmake)
message("protobuf_generate function defined at ${pb_cmake}") #for sanity check
include(${pb_cmake})

target_include_directories(cengine PRIVATE ${_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(grpc_cpp_plugin_location $<TARGET_FILE:grpc_cpp_plugin>)
message("gRPC plugin is at ${grpc_cpp_plugin_location}") #for sanity check

# Protobuf/Grpc source files
set(PROTO_SRC_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/service/proto)
set(PROTO_GEN_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/gen)
set(PROTO_FILES
    ${PROTO_SRC_DIR}/first_service.proto
    ${PROTO_SRC_DIR}/second_service.proto
)

# Add Library target with protobuf sources
add_library(service_proto OBJECT ${PROTO_FILES})
target_link_libraries(service_proto
    PUBLIC
        protobuf::libprotobuf
        grpc
        grpc++
)
target_include_directories(service_proto PUBLIC ${PROTO_GEN_DIR})

# Compile protobuf and grpc files in myproto target to cpp
protobuf_generate(
    TARGET service_proto
    LANGUAGE cpp
    GENERATE_EXTENSIONS .pb.hpp .pb.cpp
    PROTOC_OUT_DIR "${PROTO_GEN_DIR}"
)
protobuf_generate(
    TARGET service_proto
    LANGUAGE grpc
    GENERATE_EXTENSIONS .grpc.pb.hpp .grpc.pb.cpp
    PLUGIN "protoc-gen-grpc=${grpc_cpp_plugin_location}"
    PROTOC_OUT_DIR "${PROTO_GEN_DIR}"
)
```

The output of my full CMake run is:

```
>cmake -B ../out -S . -G "MinGW Makefiles"
--
-- 23.0.0
CMake Deprecation Warning at third_party/grpc/third_party/zlib/CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


protobuf_generate function defined at [REDACTED]
gRPC plugin is at $<TARGET_FILE:grpc_cpp_plugin>
-- Configuring done (1.2s)
-- Generating done (13.5s)
-- Build files have been written to: C:/src/out
```

I've validated with the official `protoc` tool that my file is syntactically correct and can generate gRPC service definitions. So that's not the problem. But I am out of ideas as to what else it could be.

Does anyone have any ideas? Or suggestions on how I can continue debugging this? I'm pretty new to CMake, so I am probably missing some context on how to debug it

Comment: Did *anything* get created in `c:\src\out`? That appears to be where it's writing things. Also, it's been a while since I've used `cmake` but doesn't it just generate a (for example) makefile that you then need to process with `make`? If my (admittedly vague) recollection is correct, the `pb.cc` and `pb.h` files won't be generated until then.

Comment: The output you show is about **configuration stage** (when you run `cmake`). Protoc files are created at **build stage** (when you run `make` or other build tool), alongside with compiling the library itself.

Comment: Thank you! That's the answer. I guess I should probably have read the documentation before starting, but who ever does that